# Multi auth while one guard should be multi-tenant plus socialite

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-5.7

So, i need to have a multi-auth system which is fairly straight forward 
(going to use the following just to make it easy on me: https://packagist.org/packages/bitfumes/laravel-multiauth)

However the problematic part of all this is that one of them guards should be multi-tenant, i'll explain: 
the first guard is for users, simple and ordinary. 
each user has its own blog. 
each blog is a "separate website". 
the second guard is for readers, each reader should be able to signup to each blog individually, even with a different password. 
so the same email should be able to register multiple times granted its a different blog. 
not only that, readers should be able to signing using socialite which just make this even more complicated. 
the problem is that i have no earthly idea how to achieve that logic using laravel, any advice?